# Not able to invoke @GET in Jersey Rest with @PathParam

Tags: rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Below is the structure of my Restful API

```
@GET
@Path("/getprovider/{queryKey}/requests/{queryValue}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getApiProv(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@PathParam("queryKey") String queryKey, @PathParam("queryValue") String queryValue) {
..........
..........
}
```

while invoking it with below url http://localhost:8080/v1/getprovider/service/requests/abc_demo

it is showing

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /v1/getprovider/service/requests/abc_demo
Reason:
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)

    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)

    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)

    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)

    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to get why it is not even going to method body. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` says that the request body will contain a valid JSON object, but the error message says you have not provided one.  Did you mean to add that `@Consumes`, and if so, did you supply a JSON object in the request body?

(Note that the request body for `GET` is not widely supported, and if you're actually trying to consume that content, then your endpoint is likely not *idempotent*, which is a key property of HTTP GET.  If you actually want to consume a JSON in the request body, then you should switch to `@PUT` or `@POST`).

Comment: I tried to remove @Consumes from the code. But it is showing unsupported media type. In that scenario, what should be the content type?

Comment: @SnehasishJana What are you using as a client?  Why is the client specifying a Content-Type header at all for a GET request?

Comment: I am using RESTClient in firefox. I have removed @Consumes from code and didn't mention any Content-Type header. But still in Response, it is showing Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type. Also, while deploying, I am getting this Warning:
A HTTP GET method,....should not consume any entity.

Also in server log, below is error msg while invoking
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, and Java type interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found

Comment: @SnehasishJana Do you have another member injection in the JAX-RS class that you've not shown that would cause the request body to be read (e.g., `@FormParam`)?  Otherwise, I'm not sure why getEntity is being called.

Comment: @SnehasishJana You need `@Context` to inject `HttpServletRequest/Response` like that.